# Google Protobuf Version between Gazebo 1.3 and Gazebo 1.4

Tags: gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am migrating from Gazebo 1.3.1 to Gazebo 1.4 now.

My google protoc version is 2.4.1. It was fine with Gazebo 1.3.1

But, I got problem after installing Gazebo 1.4.
When I compiling my plugin, I always got following errors.

```
/usr/local/include/gazebo-1.4/gazebo/msgs/topic_info.pb.h:17:2: error: #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
/usr/local/include/gazebo-1.4/gazebo/msgs/topic_info.pb.h:18:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please
/usr/local/include/gazebo-1.4/gazebo/msgs/topic_info.pb.h:19:2: error: #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
```

I found that the required google protoc version is changed from 2.4.0~2.4.1 to 2.3.

Below is /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.4/gazebo/msgs/server_control.pb.h .

```
#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 2003000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 2003000 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif
```

Do I need to downgrade google protoc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1187/google-protobuf-version-between-gazebo-1.3-and-gazebo-1.4/) by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Reading carefully the output, looks like you compiled and installed gazebo using a previous version of protobuf (probably 2.3). Now you have a newer version (2.4) and the previous compiled code using 2.3 can not work with current installed version.

I would try to compile gazebo with the new 2.4 protobuf library and install it again. If re-compiling is not an option, yes, downgrade the protobuf libraries should work.

I compile gazebo everyday against 2.4.1 protobuf library and it is perfectly compatible.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on 2013-02-08**:
I cleanup and recompiled using 2.4. Now, it works fine! Thanks.